# Magento won't allow me to instantiate my model using the factory pattern

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento Enterprise Edition and cannot understand the following:

This works:

```
 require_once 'app/Mage.php';
 Mage::app();
 $order = Mage::getModel("Spree_OrderSummary_Model_Order");
 $order->sayHi();
```

This does NOT work:

```
 require_once 'app/Mage.php';
 Mage::app();
 $order = Mage::getModel('spree/order');
 $order->sayHi();
```

It gives me the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function sayHi() on a non-object in /var/www/html/test.php on line 9

My config.xml file looks like this:

```
<config>
  <global>
    <models>
      <spree>
        <class>Spree_OrderSummary_Model</class>
      </spree>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

My model is in this path: /code/local/Spree/OrderSummary/Model/Order.php

Here is my model code:

```
<?php

class Spree_OrderSummary_Model_Order 

    public function sayHi()
    {
        echo "hi";
    }
}

?>
```

I want to be able to instantiate my Order model using magnetos built-in factory pattern, once I have that working I want to extend the model so that I can use it to retrieve entires that I have in a custom database table called "spree_orders".

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `Mage::getModel('spree_ordersummary/order')` ?

Comment: @scrowler - same error unfortunately, very frustrating issue.

Comment: Extend your class Spree_OrderSummary_Model_Order with Mage_Core_Model_Abstract and try. Like `class Spree_OrderSummary_Model_Order extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`

Comment: @GirishSH The same error still occurs.

Comment: @Jason Here i tested the same thing in my local machine, It's works fine. You delete the contents of 'Your_Magento_Directory/var/cache/' and try

Comment: But I tried in my existing controller, You are working on a external file. So have a look on the files which are in `Your_Magento_Directory\shell\`.. you may get some idea

Comment: @Girish - THANK YOU, clearing the cache worked, cannot believe that was the issue, I have been stuck in work on this for 2 days. By any chance are you interested in some freelance / contract magento work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72263/discussion-between-girish-sh-and-jason).

Comment: Yes ofcourse, You can contact me on girishshn@gmail.com